# Trace and filter http traffic on a different port other than port 80 (8986 for instance) going to a remote machine in Fiddler v4.4.5.9?

Tags: port, fiddler

Is it possible to capture and filter http traffic on a differnt port (other than port 80) that are going to a remote machine. I'm looking to trace traffic on port 8986 in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler doesn't care at all what port the HTTP/HTTPS traffic is coming from or going to. It's a proxy, which means that any traffic sent to it is shown.

What application are you trying to track? What networking code does it use?

See http://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp for common proxy configuration steps.